# Is there an algorithm that can find a solution that solves the most number of equations in a linear system of equations?

Tags: algorithms, optimization, linear-programming, program-optimization

My apologies if this question makes no sense. I am trying to find an algorithm that can solve a linear system of equations. Unlike most problems like this, this algorithm does not need to find a solution set that solves the entire set of equations. It only needs to solve the MOST number of these equations. For example, if a given linear system has $n$ equations, then the solution set returned by the algorithm should "fit" the most possible number of equations in the system.

**Example:** if there are $N$ linear equations in a system $S$ of linear equations, then the algorithm should return a solution set that solves $m$ linear equations in $S$, where $m\le N$.

Based on what I have researched, none of the algorithms I know of will do this. Hopefully I am just missing something and I can get pointed into the right direction. Thanks.

Also, I forgot to add in that the given system of equations will have 10,000-1,000,000 variables, with x being Sparse. Is there a mod 2 algorithm or something similar to it that works on very large matricies?

Comment: MOST is a vague term. And you said m=n is valid.

Comment: @kelalaka yes I specified a little more. Thanks. Yes m = n is a valid but not a necessity; if m = n thats great but if m < n that's fine as long as m is the largest number of solvable equations in the system

Comment: I’m assuming everything is done mid 2. In this case, it is NP-hard to approximate better than a factor 2 (which you can get from a random assignment) even if each equation involves only three variables, a problem known as 3LIN,

Comment: Your example does not help to understand the question (at least to me). I suggest to remove the "example" part.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus THis has definitely helped; Thank you. I forgot to add in that the given system of equations will have 10,000-1,000,000 variables, with x being Sparse. Is there a mod 2 algorithm or something similar to it that works on very large matricies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\mathsf{3LIN}$ is the following problem:

> Given a set of linear equations of the form $x_i \oplus x_j \oplus x_k = b$, where $1 \leq i,j,k \leq n$ and $b$ is a bit, find an assignment for the bits $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ that satisfies the largest number of equations.

There is a simple 1/2-approximation algorithm, which simply chooses a random assignment. Such an assignment satisfies half of the equations in expectation, and so at least 1/2 of the optimum. Using the method of conditional expectations, it is routine to derandomize this algorithm.

Håstad, in his paper [Some optimal inapproximability results](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.16.5701&rep=rep1&type=pdf), showed that it is NP-hard to approximate 3LIN to within $1/2+\epsilon$ for any $\epsilon > 0$. In other words, the trivial algorithm mentioned above gives the optimal approximation ratio.